# Good source for learn MIPS Architecture using bare-instructions

Tags: assembly, mips

So my professor is teaching MIPS and is only allowing us to use bare-instructions. I have trouble understanding her and typically used the recommended textbook for prior lessons. However, for MIPS, the textbook teaches everything in psuedo-instruction.

I tried looking online to see if I can find a good textbook, website, or youtuve video that teaches how to use MIPS w/ bare-instruction but all of them teach with the psuedo instructions.

Anyone know any good resource? Particularly, I'm trying to learn all ways to perform the various loops

Comment: Unfortunately _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"_. That said, you can use a disassembler to figure out what each pseudoinstruction does if you can't find any documentation for it. They are quite simple though so you should have no trouble figuring them out after some thought.

Comment: When I'm using the MARS simulator to answer MIPS questions on SO, the disassembly view in the debugger shows the bare instructions for every pseudo instruction in the source code (some are actually implemented in inefficient way, I wrote an email with improvements to the authors, but they didn't ever respond back about my optimized proposals). Also MARS has help explaining both bare and pseudo instruction functionality.

Comment: So probably start there, use some good tutorial to learn basics including pseudo ops to make some tasks simpler (for example doing `la` manually is IMO pure malice on lector side, as explaining how computer memory works and how assembly is operating with it is complex enough, adding to that the need to explain `lui` and bit math is IMO useless distraction). Once you somewhat understand basic MIPS assembly and you are capable to solve simple tasks, and you did learn how to use debugger, start to check out how the pseudo ops are converted into bare, and try to figure out your own patterns too.

Comment: but I don't think there's anything particularly special about loops, there's few pseudo branch instructions making the code somewhat easier to read (like using `blt` when the algorithm says `(x < y)`), but they are easy to avoid, if you actually understand how loops are constructed, and you understand the bare MIPS instructions well, you can also often modify the algorithm to avoid branch constructs which are more difficult to build with bare ins., like using mostly `==` and `!=` conditions instead of `>`, etc... My main quarrel will be `la`, in MARS that makes `.data` labels almost unusable.

Comment: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html is my go-to for classic MIPS non-pseudo instructions.  Or you could just write in code normally, assemble it with MARS, and look at the disassembly to see what instructions you really got.  If you can't remember whether something is a pseudo-instruction or not, just try it!

Comment: Re: ways to perform loops: there are nearly unlimited ways to do anything.  For writing *good* loops in asm, have a look at [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926).  (x86 examples, but the concepts apply generally.)

Comment: note that it also depends on MIPS ISA version. For example `ror` is a real instruction on newer MIPS versions